# It's possible to make the navigator adapt to the size of the child?

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

I have a navigator and a map nested in a Stack, the children of the navigator have a dynamic size.
Only the navigator forces himself to take all the space he can and cover the map behind him. It is therefore impossible to move the map.
It's possible to make the navigator adapt to the size of the child?

```
class Home extends StatefulWidget {
  Home({Key key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _HomeState createState() => _HomeState();
}

class _HomeState extends State<Home> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Stack(
        children: [
          StreamProvider(
            create: (context) => LocationService().locationStream,
            child: MapView()
          ),
          Positioned(
            width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width * 1,
            bottom: 0,
            child: ConstrainedBox(
              constraints: BoxConstraints(
                maxHeight: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height * 1,
                maxWidth: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width * 1
              ),
              child: navigator(),
            )
          ),
        ],
      )
    );
  }

  navigator() {
    return Navigator(
      initialRoute: 'anyview',
      onGenerateRoute: (settings) {
        Widget view;
        switch (settings.name) {
          case 'anyview':
            view = AnyViewDraggableScrollableSheet();
            break;
          case 'otheranyview':
            view = OtherAnyViewDraggableScrollableSheet();
            break;
        }
        var builder = (BuildContext _) {
          return view;
        };
        return MaterialPageRoute(builder: builder, settings: settings);
      },
    );
  }
}
```

Here's a demo of the problem, the navigator takes all the available space and therefore blocks it by tapping on the red block.
https://dartpad.dev/cd1c4d8f1067db0cc65ea2f62c2cbaad

Answer (score 0):

Navigator manages a stack of routes from which you can either push routes to pages into or pop routes from. If you are trying to have a certain container in the same page above your Map , I don't think that the Navigator is the right widget to use unless you actually want to have a page above it.

I propose that you use a sliding up panel that can be placed at the bottom of the page above your map and the user can just slide it up to use or view any information or buttons that you wish to play on it.

If you do not wish to create one yourself , I have had success by using this package in the past in a same case scenario.

[Sliding up panel package](https://pub.dev/packages/sliding_up_panel)

Also , I believe that the easier way to use Navigator is simply
 `Navigator.push(context, MaterialPageRoute(builder: (BuildContext context) => MyPage()));`
 if you wish to route to a different Page from the one you are currently at and `Navigator.pop(context);`
 if you wish to go back to a previous page. There are many other more specific methods for pushing and popping that you can look up in the detailed Flutter documentation.

Comment: Thank you for your response.  I just realized that my example is not good because I put only one route when there are actually 3 and it made you think that I wanted to display only one widget.

Route 2 in the navigator depends on the data in view 1 and route 2 in view 3. 
 
Correct me if I'm wrong but the navigator is the widget I need so that the user push back to. 

But the plugin you advised me is not bad, I will surely use it in another context, thank you. 

I edited my question to better understand the problem.

Comment: @YacineBelarbi have you solved it? I have a similar use case...

Comment: @RaulMabe No I had to change my strategy. I used widget stacks